# How to prevent GNU Make from executing when a variable definition has trailing spaces

Tags: makefile, gnu, gnu-make

I had a simple variable definition in my makefile:

```
THIS         := ~/edan
```

and it had trailing spaces in the line.

Later, when I defined another variable in terms of this one:

```
WARES       := $(THIS)/wares
```

the actual variable defined was `/home/directory/edan   wares`

and then the `make clean` rule removed `/home/directory/edan` instead of what I wanted it to.

How can I prevent a makefile from executing if a line has trailing spaces?

Comment: Ouch!  Probably better not to remove folders based on their absolute names -- use a relative path like `rm -rf ./wares`.  If it isn't a subdirectory from where your makefile is located, use: `( cd $(THIS) && rm -rf ./wares )`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you could write the Makefile so that it checks the variable for trailing whitespace and exits if it finds some, there are better ways of dealing with this situation.

In this instance, I would recommend using the `addsuffix` function to catenate `$(THIS)` and `/wares` instead of doing it manually. The `addsuffix` function will strip the trailing whitespace for you. In other words:

```
WARES := $(addsuffix /wares,$(THIS))
```

If you *really* want it to exit if it discovers trailing whitespace, you could do this:

```
THIS := ~/edan
ifneq "$(THIS)" "$(strip $(THIS))"
    $(error Found trailing whitespace)
endif
```