# Trailing comments after variable assignment subvert comparison

Tags: comments, makefile, gnu-make

In GNU make, trailing comments appended to variable assignments prevent subsequent comparison (via `ifeq`) from working correctly.

Here's the Makefile...

```
  A = a
  B = b ## trailing comment
  C = c

  RESULT :=

ifeq "$(A)" "a"
  RESULT += a
endif

ifeq "$(B)" "b"
  RESULT += b
endif

ifeq "$(C)" "c"
  RESULT += c
endif

rule:
    @echo RESULT=\"$(RESULT)\"
    @echo A=\"$(A)\"
    @echo B=\"$(B)\"
    @echo C=\"$(C)\"
```

Here's the output...

```
$ make
RESULT=" a c"
A="a"
B="b "
C="c"
```

As you can see from the displayed value of `RESULT`, the `ifeq` was affected by the presence of the comment in the assignment of `B`.  Echoing the variable `B`, shows that **the problem is not the comment, but the intervening space**.

The obvious solution is to explicitly [strip](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions) the whitespace prior to comparison like so...

```
ifeq "$(strip $(B))" "b"
  RESULT += b
endif
```

However this seems error prone.  Since the `strip` operation is not needed unless/until a comment is used, you can leave out the `strip` and everything will initially work just fine -- so chances are you won't always remember to add the `strip`.  Later, if someone adds a comment when setting the variable, the Makefile no longer works as expected.

Note: There is a closely related issue, as demonstrated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4053379/86967), that trailing whitespace can break string compares even if there is no comment.

Question: Is there a more **fool-proof** way to deal with this issue?

Comment: Just to be 100% clear, it's not the trailing comment that is the problem.  It's the whitespace BEFORE the comment.  If you write `b = b# trailing comment`, so there's no trailing space before the comment character, it works fine although it looks ugly.  And, there's no foolproof way to handle it other than don't add trailing space.  Most decent editors will have a mode that detects and highlights trailing whitespace, or even just removes it automatically when you save.  Use that.  I won't try to defend the bizarre decisions the make designers made except to say, it was a long time ago.

Comment: By the way, here is an interesting thread where the OP has the exact same problem (but asks a different question): http://old.nabble.com/White-Space-Problems--Again-td22756435.html

Comment: @MadScientist: I agree with your suggestion to use an editor that highlights trailing spaces.  But just because I use one, doesn't mean that everyone else will.  I would like my Makefiles to work in a reasonable way even for people who don't know all of the tricks and traps.

Answer (score 8):

This is not something particular to GNU Make; rather, `make` is [defined by POSIX to work this way](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html#tag_20_76_13_05):

> `string1 = [string2]`
>
> The macro named *string1* is defined as having the value of *string2*, where *string2* is defined as all characters, if any, after the `<equals-sign>`, up to a comment character (`#`) or an unescaped `<newline>`. Any `<blank>` characters immediately before or after the `<equals-sign>` shall be ignored.

This can be construed as a feature allowing you to clearly create variables with trailing whitespace:

```
FOO = stuff  # this macro has two trailing spaces
BAR = something else# and this one has none
```

though probably usually it would be clearer to reorganise the places you use `$(FOO)` rather than depend on it having obscure whitespace.

Probably the best way to deal with this is just to avoid it: have a convention that you **do not** put comments on variable definition lines (except very occasionally to make intentional whitespace explicit).  Instead of writing this:

```
A = a # list of apples
B = b # list of bananas
C = c # list of carrots
```

write this:

```
# list of apples
A = a
# list of bananas
B = b
# list of carrots
C = c
```

This tends to be the style in GNU projects (see for example [the bottom of this page](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Directory-Variables.html)), though I don't recall whether this is documented anywhere.

Incidentally, when examining whitespace you probably want to quote your variables in your `echo` command more:

```
rule:
   @echo 'RESULT="$(RESULT)"'
```

In your `echo RESULT=\"$(RESULT)\"` version, `$(RESULT)` is not quoted from the shell, so tabs and multiple spaces are being misleadingly displayed as single spaces.

Comment: Thank you for the good insights.  I will say though, that I do not like the convention that you propose for two reasons: 1) It is more cumbersome to edit and harder to read (in my opinion). 2) It is a non-intuitive requirement that will be problematic to communicate to all future users of all Makefiles.

Comment: Also, thanks for the note about quotes.  I don't think I will ever fully understand how strings are manipulated by the POSIX shell.  I guess `make` and `shell` have the shared trait of quirky string management -- in both cases based on decisions made a long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some raw ideas that I have:

- Make it a policy to *always* use `strip` with `ifeq`

  - Not using `strip` would be a rare exception and would require an explanation in the comments.
- Don't manually set configuration variables inside of a Makefile

  - Find or create some other tool to do that.
  - maybe the POSIX shell will suffice (although I think the nuances of shell variables may be worse than those of make).
  - I suspect that the [GNU build system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_build_system) (Autoconf/Automake/etc.) addresses this, but my feeling is that this is overkill for most purposes.
- Use some kind of "lint" tool to find these kind of problems

  - I'm not aware of the existence of any such tool.
- Modify GNU make to fix this problem.

  - Preferably minimizing the impact on existing Makefiles.
  - Modify the make language so that by default the trailing-spaces are stripped
- Use a more modern build tool instead of GNU make

Comment: Using `strip` doesn't scale.  Besides, `ifeq` is not the only case where the trailing spaces can be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly, but perhaps more foolproof.  Anyone who edits this in the future might at least notice that you, perhaps, made it ugly on purpose.

```
A = $(strip a )##
B = $(strip b )## trailing comment
C = $(strip c )##
```