# make `notdir`/`strip` with CURDIR combination seem to have different behaviour in definition versus conditional [comments and variables]

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, stm32cubeide

I am using GNU make version 4.2.1 with an Eclipse framework called 'STM32CubeIDE'.  It is structured with targets in sub-directories such as 'Release', 'Debug' and 'bootloader' that have the main makefile.  In the directory above, there are optional support files to modify the build behaviour such as,

```
    -include ../makefile.init
    # Define lists of source files
    -include ../makefile.defs
    # Define make variable and rules
    -include ../makefile.targets
```

The above makefile is generated automatically by Java code within the Eclipse/STM32CubeIDE framework.

I have a **makefile.defs** and I attempt a definition like this,

```
TYPE=$(strip $(notdir $(CURDIR)))  # Debug, Release or bootloader
```

However, the $(strip) seems to be in-effective.  If I apply it directly in a condition, it works.

```
ifeq ($(strip $(TYPE)),bootloader)
$(info bootloader active)
endif
```

I don't understand what make facilities would cause this?  The purpose of 'TYPE' is to be used in the subsequent **makefile.targets** to over-ride the linker commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strip` definitely works.  But it only strips the content that you provide to the `strip` function.  Here:

```
TYPE=$(strip $(notdir $(CURDIR)))  # Debug, Release or bootloader
```

the `strip` will remove whitespace from the results of expanding `$(notdir $(CURDIR))` just as you'd expect.  But after that you add more whitespace to the end, by adding the   `# Debug, ...`

The standard behavior for make variables etc. is that *preceding* space is trimmed automatically, and *trailing* space is not trimmed at all.

You can use this:

```
TYPE=$(strip $(notdir $(CURDIR)))# Debug, Release or bootloader
```

By removing the extra spaces between the value and the comment.  Another option is to put the comment first:

```
# Debug, Release or bootloader
TYPE=$(strip $(notdir $(CURDIR)))
```

Or you can do something like this (since `CURDIR` is a static variable you might as well use `:=`):

```
TYPE = $(notdir $(CURDIR))  # Debug, Release or bootloader
TYPE := $(strip $(TYPE))
```

Comment: That makes sense.  The variable are very finicky about white space.  It seems best not to comment on the same line.  Is there a duplicate of this?  The 'side' notation makes the comment compact and out of the way for the reader.  I can use a comment block at the head of variable definitions that give details about each.  I prefer to keep comments 'out of the way', but available for when people might need them.

Comment: I don't understand the question _Is there a duplicate of this?_

Comment: I didn't understand what the problem was before.  I think this one?  
 Thank you for your help, documentation, and work on GNU make itself. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953825/trailing-comments-after-variable-assignment-subvert-comparison